# Orifice flow meter equation applicability, modeling leak flow

Tags: mechanical-engineering, fluid-mechanics, measurements

I am trying to determine the correct equation to model ideal gas flow rate through an orifice as a function of pressure.  The equation below I found in *Marks' Handbook for Mech Eng 8th Ed,* p. 3-64 which it says is for "ASME Orifice Meters."  It states these orifice meters do not exhibit choked flow, which implies to me that the equation is useable for any ratio of upstream to downstream pressure $P_1/P_2,$ even if it's greater than 2.

Marks' Equation:

$$ \dot m = CEYA \sqrt {2 \rho \Delta P  }   $$

$$ C = \rm Discharge~Coefficient         $$

$$ E = \frac 1 {\sqrt{1-\beta^4}}$$

$$Y = 1 -(0.41+0.35 \beta^4) \frac {\Delta P}{kP_1} $$

Alternatively, ISO 5167-2 gives the following roughly similar formula for expansibility factor $Y$:

$$Y = 1-(0.351+0.256\beta^4+0.93\beta^8)\left[ 1-\left(\frac {P_2}{P_1}\right)^{1/k} \right]        $$

But in contrast to the *Marks'* equation, the ISO explicitly limits the equation to $P_2/P_1>0.75$ [i.e. $P_1/P_2 < 1.33$], which is well within the subsonic regime.  (They also limit it to relatively large orifice meters, orifice diameter 12.5 mm or greater.)  This makes it seem like the functional relationship may only be valid for fairly low ranges of $P_1/P_2$, and above this the flow may become choked.

My question:

Can the first equation, or one like it, be used for a range of $P_1/P_2$ greater than 2 and less than 2?  Will the flow choke above the critical ratio (references say that square-edged orifice plates do not choke)?  Does anyone have experience or advice in this area?

My goal is to model upstream pressure loss over time where the pressure ratio can pass by this limit.  The actual geometry of the flow obstruction is unknown (it is flow through a small leak path), but may roughly approximate an orifice.

Thank you.

Note:

$\dot m =$ mass flow rate

$\beta = $ diameter ratio $d/D$

$A =$ orifice area

$\rho =$ density

$\Delta P = $ pressure difference

$P_1 = $ pressure upstream

$P_2 = $ pressure downstream

$k =$ specific heat ratio

Comment: Does the ISO use the ASME orifice meters or some different?